# Geometry, Triangles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

In the figure, $BC$ is parallel to $DE$. If area of ∆ $PDE$ is $3/7$ of area of ∆ $ADE$, then what is the ratio of $BC$ and $DE$?

I tried finding ratios of height of ∆ $ABC$, $PDE$ & $BPC$, and trying to figure out some commonality, but it didn't​ work out.

P.s. it is not my homework.

Ratio is 5:2. Not sure how.

[image]

Comment: and where are the Points $D$ and $E$ situated?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner refer to image. D lies on AB and E lies on AC. DE is parallel to BC

Comment: No proof (yet), but ... Playing with a [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org) sketch, I find that we always seem to have $|\overline{BC}|:|\overline{DE}| = 5:2$.

Comment: @Blue  answer is 5:2. But what do mean?

Comment: @Ajax: When you know the answer, you should add that information to your question. After all, you want to make life as easy as possible for those who want to help you. (I'm not sure what you mean by "But what do mean?" Perhaps my "GeoGebra" reference was unclear. [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org) is software that constructs accurate, dynamic geometric diagrams (among other things). Using that to construct various triangles led me to suspect that the desired ratio in your problem is $5:2$. Of course, examples are not proof, so there's still work to be done.)

Comment: @Blue well. I have that answer written on a piece of paper. Wasn't fully sure. Now I am. !

Comment: FYI: With a quick-and-dirty coordinate argument, I can show that, in general, $$|\triangle PDE| \;:\; |\triangle ADE| \;=\; p\;:\;q \quad\implies\quad |\overline{BC}|\;:\;|\overline{DE}| \;=\; (p+q)\;:\;|p-q|$$ There should be a straightforward geometric demonstration of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may assume $$A=(0,0),\quad  B=(1,0),\quad C=(0,1), \quad  D=(r,0),\quad  E=(0,r)$$
for some $r\in\>]0,1[\>$. Intersecting $EB$ with $C D$ gives $P=\bigl({r\over1+r},{r\over1+r}\bigr)$. $ED$ and $PA$ intersect orthogonally at the midpoint $M=\bigl({r\over2},{r\over2}\bigr)$ of $ED$. The ratio of the two triangle areas  in question is therefore given by $${|PM|\over |MA|}={\sqrt{2}\bigl({r\over 1+r}-{r\over2}\bigr)\over\sqrt{2}\,{r\over2}}={1-r\over1+r}\ .$$
Since this ratio has to be ${3\over7}$ it follows that $r={2\over5}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here comes my attempt of a geometric derivation of the sought ratio.[image]

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $\overline{BC}$. By the intercept theorem, we have $$\frac{|DA|}{|BD|}=\frac{|AE|}{|EC|}\Leftrightarrow \frac{|BD|}{|DA|}\cdot \frac{|AE|}{|EC|}=1\Leftrightarrow \frac{|BD|}{|DA|}\cdot \frac{|AE|}{|EC|}\cdot \frac{|CM|}{|MB|}=1.$$
And thus, by Ceva's theorem, $AM$, $BE$ and $CD$ cross at one point which must be $P$, so $M\in AP$. Then define $Q,R\in DE$ so that $AQ\perp DE$ and $PR\perp DE$. Then we have $$\frac{|PR|}{|AQ|}=\frac{|PDE|}{|ADE|}=\frac{3}{7}.$$ Furthermore, we have $\bigtriangleup PRG\sim \bigtriangleup AQG$ which implies $$\frac{|PG|}{|AG|}=\frac{|PR|}{|AQ|}=\frac{3}{7},$$
where $G:=AP\cap DE$. Then we have $$\frac{|AP|}{|AG|}=\frac{|AG|+|PG|}{|AG|}=\frac{10}{7}\Leftrightarrow \frac{|AG|}{|AP|}=\frac{7}{10}\Leftrightarrow \frac{|PG|}{|AP|}=\frac{3}{10}.$$ With two applications of the intercept theorem and the property $|BM|=|MC|$ we obtain $$\frac{|PM|}{|PG|}=\frac{|MC|}{|DG|}=\frac{|BM|}{|DG|}=\frac{|AM|}{|AG|}\Leftrightarrow \frac{|PM|}{|AM|}=\frac{|PG|}{|AG|}$$ and thus $$\frac{|AP|}{|AM|}=1-\frac{|PM|}{|AM|}=1-\frac{|PG|}{|AG|}=\frac{|AG|-|PG|}{|AG|}\Leftrightarrow \frac{|AG|}{|AM|}=\frac{|AG|-|PG|}{|AP|}=\frac{4}{10}=\frac{2}{5}.$$ We then use the intercept theorem to deduce $$\frac{|DG|}{|GE|}=\frac{|BM|}{|MC|}=1\Leftrightarrow |DG|=|GE|.$$ Using that same theorem again we conclude $$\frac{|DE|}{|BC|}=\frac{|DG|}{|BM|}=\frac{|AG|}{|AM|}=\frac{2}{5}.$$ And thus, we have $|BC|:|DE|=5:2$, as desired.

At least in the case $|ADE|>|PDE|$ this proof can be easily generalized to Blue's statement $$|PDE|:|ADE|=p:q\Rightarrow |BC|:|DE|=(p+q):|p-q|.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $h$ be the altitude of triangles $DBC$ and $EBC$ with respect to base $BC$, and $h'$ be the altitude of $ADE$ with respect to base $DE$. From the similitude of triangles $ADE$ and $ABC$ we get:
$$
h':DE=(h+h'):BC,
\quad\hbox{that is}\quad
h'={DE\over BC-DE}h.
$$
Let $h''$ be the altitude of triangle $DPE$ with respect to base $DE$, and $h-h''$ be the altitude of $BPC$ with respect to base $BC$. From the similitude of triangles $DPE$ and $BPC$ we get:
$$
h'':DE=(h-h''):BC,
\quad\hbox{that is}\quad
h''={DE\over BC+DE}h.
$$
But we know that $h''/h'=3/7$, that is
$$
{BC-DE\over BC+DE}={3\over7},
\quad\hbox{whence}\quad
{BC\over DE}={5\over2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let BE meet CD at P. We also let DE be 1 unit and BC = k units, for some k.

According to the given, we can also let [ADE] = 7h and [PDE] = 3h for some non-zero constant h.

[image]

Fact-1) When two triangles have the same altitude, the ratio of their areas is proportional to the ratio of their bases.

Then, [PBD] = [PCE] and $\dfrac {[DBP]}{[DPE]} = \dfrac {k}{1}$.

Fact-2) If two objects are similar, the ratio of their areas is equal to the square of ratios of their corresponding sides.

Noting that $\triangle ADE \sim \triangle ABC$ and $\triangle PDE \sim \triangle PCB$, we have

[PBC] = … = $3hk^2$; and [ABC] = … = $7hk^2$.

∴ [BCED] = [ABC] – [ADE] = $7hk^2 – 7h$

[DPB] = $\dfrac {(7hk^2 – 7h) – 3h – 3hk^2}{2} = 2hk^2 – 5h$

$\dfrac {[DBP]}{[DPE]} = \dfrac {k}{1} = \dfrac {2hk^2 – 5h }{3h}$

After eliminating the “h” , we will get $k = \dfrac {5}{2}$ as the only feasible solution from the resultant quadratic.